How do I convey extreme speed to readers?
In my Urban Fantasy story, I'm trying to introduce and establish an antagonist with light-based symbolism. They're supposed to be the fastest character, referencing the speed of light. Every time they act, they move so quickly it should make even the readers feel like the character is fast.
How do I convey extreme speed to readers specifically?

You convey extreme speed visually,and perhaps as accompanying sound.
If you want the reader to feel something, you need to make that felt by a POV character in the story. Reader's tend to identify with the hero of the story (or one of the heroes).
Here's one invented for you: Presume Jenna is the hero, Roger is the antagonist, but Jenna doesn't know that yet.

Jenna wasn't sure what happened, one instant the mugger was pointing a gun at Roger -- she heard a soft whoosh, and Roger had the gun in his left hand, finger on the trigger, the muzzle close to the mugger's right eye.
With quiet, slow malice, Roger said, "It is time for you to run away. Do you understand?"
The mugger's eyes widened, he tried to turn and fell but managed to scramble to his feet and run away. As Jenna watched, lips parted in shock, Roger unloaded the gun, threw the bullets into the street, and checked that the barrel was clean.
Roger looked at her with a slight smile. "Are you okay, Jenna? It's over."
"How...how did you do that?"
Roger shrugged. "Kind of a magic trick I picked up as a kid. I told you, magic was a hobby of mine."
He hefted the gun. "I'll turn this in, the cops might want to see if it has been used in other crimes."
He pocketed it, grinned at her, and offered her his hand. "One more gun off the streets, amiright?"
Jenna realized her mouth was still open, and self-consciously closed it, and took Roger's hand. "Hobby my sweet ass, you could go pro."
"Thought about it. It does come in handy, sometimes."

We want the reader to identify with Jenna, so we tell this from her POV.
Readers are constantly trying to build a movie in their head based on what you write. But more than a movie, you can talk about smells, temperature, feelings. But they are trying, with their own imagination, to fill in setting and actions, to create a kind of lived experience.
When I put down the book, I don't remember the description of the castle. I remember the castle, the image the author built in my mind, and the parts that came from my own imagination. I don't remember the words in the above description, I remember the scene I imagined, prompted by those words.
If I were to rewrite it tomorrow, I might use different words, but my imagination of the scene would be the same.
Our primary senses are going to be sight, then sound, then other senses like smell, touch, temperature, aches and pains.
Focus on the sensory experience of magic, and the effects of magic. Don't rely on specific words, rely on the emotions it creates in others (like Jenna above). The reader gets that Roger's speed is unbelievable because it is unbelievable to Jenna.

What about writing style? Short sentences with short simple verbs and no adjectives might convey speed. A staccato style.

@TRiG That's possible, in describing a fight scene, for example. A series of fast actions. But that isn't exactly conducive to showing somebody else is fast. Using the short-sentence strategy doesn't work for the scene above, in an instant Roger goes from victim to aggressor, it is all over faster than Jenna can see it happen. As the Question says, every time they act they move so fast.... To illustrate that, we need a situation in which the fast character feels compelled to act. Also, a long list of staccato sentences can seem long. We don't go into details of how Roger got the gun.
